# Atmospheric correction of Landsat 7 slc-off images

Tags: imagery, digital-image-processing, atmospheric-correction, landsat-7

I am interested in finding the change in land cover particularly forests.
I am working with slc-off images (no other sensor images available for my study). I have done the gap-filling in Erdas Imagine using focal-analysis and it worked fine. I have to further atmospherically correct the images using FLAASH in Envi.

What is the right sequence of process work?

Atmospheric correction before gap-filling or Gap-filling before atmospheric correction?

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be any functional difference between the two approaches. Only potential risk that I can see is that the gapfilling in Erdas may not function properly with floating point values instead of integers, which would mean that gapfilling had to go before atmospheric correction.

However, that would be a silly bug and I'd expect both workflows to give the same result.